# How to get Google account data to fetch steps from Google Fit API on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin, google-fit

I want to access number of steps from Google Fit API on Android. I have a following piece of code and I execute `tryToAccessStepsFromGoogleFit()` when a button is clicked:

```
val FITNESS_OPTIONS: FitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .build()

private fun tryToAccessStepsFromGoogleFit() {
    val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(requireContext(), FITNESS_OPTIONS)
    // all fields of account are empty

    if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, FITNESS_OPTIONS)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Asking for permission")
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
            this,
            GOOGLE_FIT_STEPS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
            account,
            FITNESS_OPTIONS
        )
    } else { // this branch is executed which is weird
        Log.i(TAG, "Already has permissions")
        accessStepsFromGoogleFit()
    }
}

private fun accessStepsFromGoogleFit() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Accessing steps from Google Fit")

    val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(requireContext(), FITNESS_OPTIONS)

    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this.activity!!, account)
        .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            // do whatever with the result
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem getting steps: " + e.localizedMessage)
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.permission_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            // this branch is executed and error happens "4: The user must be signed in to make this API call."
        }
}
```

which is more or less similar to the one in Google Fit android API docs.

The problem is that `getAccountForExtension` doesn't seem to return any sensible account data nor showing any intent to prompt user to choose their account and grant access to Google Fit data. **What should I do to achieve that?**

---

Also, on SO I've found code that shows a dialog to choose an account:

```
private fun startSignInIntent() {
    val signInClient: GoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(
        this.activity!!,
        GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN
    )
    val intent = signInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(intent, GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_CHOSEN)
}
```

Showing the above dialog and then using `GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension` allows to fetch the data from the Fitness API but the documentation says nothing about that.

---

Possibly helpful info:

- SDK target version: 29
- Android 9
- tested on MIUI Global 11.0.4
- I've already created a project in Google Developers Console, provided SHA1, enabled Fitness for this project, etc.

Comment: Same problem here. How did you solve this?